# Deduplication Logic to pick specific set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem statement, where I need to pick up rows based on a specific logic.
For example this is what I have:

| ID | Amount | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | A |
| 1 | 15 | A |
| 1 | 28 | C |
| 1 | 28 | C |
| 1 | -15 | B |
| 2 | 30 | D |
| 2 | -30 | E |
| 2 | -30 | E |
| 2 | 18 | F |

So I first want to remove duplicated rows.
this would get me:

| ID | Amount | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | A |
| 1 | 28 | C |
| 1 | -15 | B |
| 2 | 30 | D |
| 2 | -30 | E |
| 2 | 18 | F |

Now, I want to pick rows along with the right "Item" where the amounts don't cancel each other off. For example, the output should be:

| ID | Amount | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 | C |
| 2 | 18 | F |

The logic I'm thinking of is using SUM OVER partitioned by the IDs, and then joining back to the table with the same ID and the SUMed amount. For ID 1, the sum amount would be 28, and for ID 2, it would be 18. I also need to get, Item C for ID 1, and Item F for ID 2.
Does that make sense? Or does someone have a better idea? Also, how would I code this using SQL?

This should create the initial table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    Id VARCHAR,
    Amount NUMERIC,
    Item VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO table_1 (Id, Amount, Item)
VALUES 
('1', 15, 'A'),
('1', 15, 'A'),
('1', 28, 'C'),
('1', 28, 'C'),
('1', -15, 'B'),
('2', 30, 'D'),
('2', -30, 'E'),
('2', -30, 'E'),
('2', 18, 'F');
```

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (i.e. create table + insert into table) you'll make it much easier for someone to assist. I don't have to time to type that all in.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way, but following your logic you can use `row_number` to identify duplicate rows and filter them out. Then you can use a windowed sum to identify rows which cancel and filter them out.

However I am sceptical about your logic, I mean how is it that you can remove duplicate rows like that? Maybe you have oversimplified the data? Because if it is valid in your actual data for a value to be repeated that shouldn't be duplicated or combined then the following logic would need to be improved to handle that.

```
with cte1 as (
    select *
        -- Use row number to remove duplicate rows
        , row_number() over (partition by Id, Amount, Item order by Id, Amount, Item) rn
    from #table_1
), cte2 as (
    select Id, Item
       -- Use windowed sum to identify rows which cancel out
       , sum(Amount) over (partition by Id, abs(Amount)) CancelSum
    from cte1
    where rn = 1
)
select Id, Item, CancelSum Amount
from cte2
-- Filter out cancelled rows
where CancelSum <> 0;
```

Returns:

| Id | Item | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | 28 |
| 2 | F | 18 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do your steps in a multuiple CTE and use them to find your wanted rows

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT DISTINCT Id, Amount, Item FROM table_1)
> , CTE2 AS (SELECT Id,SUM(Amount) Amount FROM CTE
> GROUP BY Id
> HAVING SUM(Amount)>0)
> SELECT Id, Amount, Item
> FROM CTE 
> WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
>               FROM CTE2
>               WHERE 
>                         CTE.Id = CTE2.Id
>                         AND CTE.Amount = CTE2.Amount)
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Amount | Item
> :- | -----: | :---
> 1  |     28 | C   
> 2  |     18 | F
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f23c0c32992d0c05badb05f150ca157d)*